# .htaccess mod_rewrite rule to match the clean URL as well as additional custom parameters

Tags: php, rest, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

This is a .htaccess file I found for my REST API that rewrites URLs in this manner: *rest.php/a/b/c/...* -> *rest.php?url=a/b/c/...*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rest.php?url=$1 [L,NC,NE]
```

I've been trying to modify this code to allow for additional GET parameters as in the current form it just ignores them and PHP only sees the 'url'. How could this be done?

I want something like this: *rest.php/a/b/c/...?filter=word* -> *rest.php?url=a/b/c/...&filter=word*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the flag `QSA` (Query String Append)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ output.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,NE]
```

Gives me for the url

```
http://localhost/rest.php/a/b/c/?var2=val2
```

the following `GET` parameters

```
array(2) { ["url"]=> string(15) "rest.php/a/b/c/" ["var2"]=> string(4) "val2" }
```

For more info see [Rewrite Flag QSA](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA)

Comment: Works as expected, thanks. Had no idea it was so simple